# Install libjpeg.so.8 to CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, libraries

I need install `libjpeg.so.8` to CentOS 6.6 but i do not understand how to do...
I have installed `libjpeg-turbo` `libjpeg-turbo-devel` but `libjpeg.so.8` there is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on why you want that particular version.  CentOS 6 has /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62

Some applications may require a specific old version.  A forum comment *[pdf2swf and libjpeg.so.8 problem](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=52492)* stated that a solution was found by adding the rpmforge repository and getting the library from that location (using [this page](http://www.theshell.guru/install-pdf2swf-swftools-on-centos-6-5/)).

Answer (score 1):

Just had this specific problem, wanted to install "Genymotion" software on Fedora 23.  This is proprietary software and you can't just recompile it against a different version of this lib, so I compiled libjpeg 8.0 from source. You can grab it [here (64bit only)](https://github.com/maciej-c/libjpeg8x64).

Remember that using binaries from random people on Internet is probably a bad idea. ;)